# System.BadImageFormatException: Invalid access to memory location

Tags: c#

I cant seem to find why this piece of codes give me System.BadImageFormatException: Invalid access to memory location

```cs
public unsafe static ulong FreeMemory()
{
    unsafe
    {
        var free = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(sizeof(ulong));
        var total = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(sizeof(ulong));

        ulong result = 0;

        var freePtr = &free;
        var totalPtr = &total;

        CUDAInterop.cuMemGetInfo(freePtr, totalPtr);

        result = (ulong)freePtr[0];

        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(free);
        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(total);

        return result;
    }
}
```

All is fine and good until it calls FreeHGlobal method, then it gives me this error
[image]

Comment: Does it work if you comment out the `CUDAInterop` line?

Comment: yes, it works. I wonder why it doesn't work in c#, since the same piece of code worked in f#

Comment: ah it seems that NativeInterop.NativePtr.ofNativeInt does something different from unsafe keyword and pointer assignment of c#